# Debugger is not working in appecelator studio

Tags: debugging, titanium, appcelerator

I have installed the appecelator studio 6. I have placed the breakpoints and when i debug either as android or ios, the code is not breaking. I have verified the axway documentation and have done the setup correctly. Can anyone suggest me if I need to change any configurations under debug configurations tab.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at this tutorial:

https://github.com/m1ga/from_zero_to_app/blob/master/chrome_safari_devtools.md

You can use the ChromeDev tools to debug you app and set breakpoints there, too. Big advantage: you don't need to use Appcelerator Studio but can use VSCode or Atom.

You could also do the old fashion way and use `console.log()` to output stuff to the console (without break-points)

*On a side note:*

Debugging works fine with studio too:
[image]

Just make sure you run in debug mode in the top left corner. I've successfully tested with the Android emulator and the demo alloy project.

Comment: Very thanks for the quick help. I was able to debug through safari. The Appcelerator Studio debugger was working fine for me and it suddenly stopped working. Is there any configurations I'm missing.

Comment: don't know :) I left Studio a long time ago and moved to Atom.

Answer (score -1):

[The current configurations in my Appcelerator Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pF9R.png)

[Is there something I need to change in the debug configurations?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV4hr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV4hr.png)